# Arithmetic Progression Formula

Tags: math, formula

I'm having trouble trying to figure out arithmetic progressions. I'm looking for a formula with an output that increases by 100 more than it's last increase... like this:

```
100, 300, 600, 1000, 1500
```

So the increase pattern looks like this:

```
(100+)200, (300+)300, (600+)400, (1000+)500, etc
```

2 hours and 2, front and back, scratch papers have yeilded no such formula. I'm hoping this makes since because my brain is literally fried right now.

This is essentially a level-up formula for an rpg.
When you are level 1 you need 100 exp to level up.
Level 1: 100 (increased by 100)

Level 2: 300 (increased by 200)

Level 3: 600 (increased by 300)

Level 4: 1000 (increased by 400)

and so on...

I don't feel like hardcoding the levels, so will someone please help me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write down all your expressions :

```
level i = leveil i-1 + i*100
level i-1 = level i-2 + i-1 * 100
...
level 1 = level 0 + 100
```

then summing up these formulas one level k Left hand side eliminate the  next one level k right hand side, and you get :

```
Level i = level 0 + sum(k , k=1 to i)*100

then level i = i*(i+1)/2 *100
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks so much! The only other thing I could think of was to make a seperate variable to add to the lvl*100. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That's just a simple triangular number equation.

```
k * n * (n + 1) / 2
```

where `k=100` and `n=1,2,3,...`. You can obtain your list like this:

```
k = 100
n_max = 10

for n in range(1, n_max):
    print k * n * (n + 1) / 2
```

where `n_max` is the number of elements you need.